# Use select to change value in Django tag

Tags: django, selection

I produce a search results page based on distance, and only display results less than some distance. I want to have a select box with different distance values, and when the user selects a different distance, the results will change.

I want the radius value in this tag to be tied to the select box:

```
{% if hospital.distance <= radius %}
Display this result
{% endif %}
```

So is there a way to use a select box to change a value in a Django tag?

Answer (score 0):

*So is there a way to use a select box to change a value in a Django tag?*

No. This takes place client side. What you want to do is use javascript. One way would be to put it in a hidden div and then display it with javascript when your condition is true.

Comment: I'm looking for something that would change what is displayed on the template